# Spark clustering with yarn

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, docker

I would like to make spark clustering with yarn. 
Do i need

1. installing hadoop master and slaves with yarn config?
2. installing hadoop master/slaves and yarn master/slaves separately?

If 1 is ok, I'm going to work with this docker image([link](https://github.com/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker)). Is it suitable for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing hadoop master and slave with yarn config is sufficient in order to run spark over yarn but then you also need to make sure that spark version you are downloading supports yarn. once installed spark should be able to access yarn configurations and required jar files related to yarn are also in path of spark.